# phpMyAdmin - The MySQL Extension is Missing

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed everything separately (Apache, PHP, MySQL and phpMyAdmin) and do not use a compilation, everything works fine till now except phpMyAdmin.

The problem I am experiencing is, that the error message states that the "MySQL extension is missing", as soon as I try to call up:

localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php

And when I call up

localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/index.php

I have two messages where I do not know if it is supposed to be like that:

> Bzip2 compression and decompression requires functions (bzopen,
>   bzcompress) which are unavailable on this system.

and:

> Zip decompression requires functions (zip_open) which are unavailable
>   on this system.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you make a php file with <?php phpinfo(); ?> in it, is the mysql extension loaded there? If not, you need to activate it in your php.ini

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At first make sure you have mysql installed properly. You can ensure it just by checking that whether you can access mysql using mysql command promp. So if you mysql is working then probably it is not loading. For that follow the steps given below

First of all, you must find your php.ini. It could be anywhere but if you create a small php file with the

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

script it will tell you where it is. Just look at the path of loaded configuration file.
Common places include /etc/apache/, /etc/php4/apache2/php.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini or even /usr/local/lib/php.ini for Windows it may be C:\Users\username\PHP\php.ini

Edit your server’s php.ini and look for the following line. Remove the ‘;’ from the start of the line and restart Apache. Things should work fine now!

```
;extension=mysql.so
```

should become

```
extension=mysql.so
```

For windows it will be

```
;extension=mysql.dll
```

should become

```
extension=mysql.dll
```

Comment: From the latest php 7.3...
; Note : The syntax used in previous PHP versions ('extension=<ext>.so' and
; 'extension='php_<ext>.dll') is supported for legacy reasons and may be
; deprecated in a future PHP major version. So, when it is possible, please
; move to the new ('extension=<ext>) syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Some linux distributions have a **php_mysql** and **php_mysqli** package to install.

Answer (score 3):

Installing `bzip2` and `zip` PHP extensions solved my issue in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-bz2
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

Use `php(you version)-(extension)` to install and enable any missing modules that is required in the phpmyadmin readme.

Comment: i am new to this. from which folder must i be running ```sudo apt-get install php7.0-bz2```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the full path in the php ini when loading the mysql dll, i.e :-

> extension=c:/php54/ext/php_mbstring.dll
>   extension=c:/php54/ext/php_mysql.dll

Then you don't need to move them to the windows folder.

Comment: You only have to add the path for each extension if you have not set "extension_dir".   It's much easier to set "extension_dir" than adding the path to every extension.  Ex: extension_dir = "c:/php/ext"

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to install the extension:

```
yum install php php-mysql httpd
```

and then restart apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

That solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just as others stated you need to remove the '`;`' from: 
`;extension=php_mysql.dll`  and 
`;extension=php_mysqli.dll`

in your php.ini to enable mysql and mysqli extensions. But **MOST IMPORTANT  of all**, you should set the `extension_dir` in your php.ini to point to your extensions directory. The default most of the time is "`ext`". You should change it to the *absolute* path to the extensions folder. i.e. if you have your xampp installed on drive C, then  `C:/xampp/php/ext` is the absolute path to the ext folder, and It should work like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

I just add

```
apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

This will ask to overwrite mysql.so from "php5-mysql".

This work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your installation is missing some php modules, there should be a list of required modules in the phpmyadmin readme. If you recently enabled the modules, try restarting the apache service / daemon.

Edit: As it seems, there is no single "enable these modules" in the docs, so enable either `mysql` or `mysqli` in your php.ini (you might need to install it first).

The two messages are not important if you do not intend to upload or download compressed file within phpMyAdmin. If you do, enable the `zlib` and / or `bz2` modules.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but it didn't help to add extension=mysql.so in my php.ini. It turned out that the mysql.so file was not in my extension folder nor anywhere else on my machine. Solved this by downloading the php source and building the extension manually and then copying it into the extension folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your php.ini file, In this file Semicolon(;) used for comment
if you see then remove semicolon ;.

```
;extension=mysql.dll
```

Now your extension is enable but you need to restart appache

```
extension=mysql.dll
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to you all, but I had to do one more thing and that is, move the libmysql.dll to the Windows System32 folder as described in the PHP manual - adding it to the Windows PATH is supposed to work too, but that one does not work for me in general.