# writing fetch_assoc() array data to table

Tags: php, mysql

What is the proper way to reference the array components from `fetch_assoc()` so that they can be inserted into another table?

Here is my current code:

```
$sql_read = "SELECT id, data1, data2, date FROM `table1`";   
$result = $mysqli->query($sql_read);    
if ($result !== false) {    
    $rows = $result->fetch_all();   
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
    $sql_write = "INSERT INTO `table2`.`load_records` (`id`, `data1`,`data2`,`date`) VALUES ('.$row['id']', '.$row['data1']', '.$row['data2']', '.$row['date']', NULL);";
}
```

Comment: what issue you are experiencing currently? I found you do not have id in your select statement, but are using as $row['id']

Comment: After correcting for the missed ID in the select statement (thanks) I am getting PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in my php error log

Comment: After you've already fetched all records via `$result->fetch_all()`, what do you expect `while($result->fetch_assoc())`to do? And you're not selecting the field `id`, so there wil be no `$row['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra field in the `VALUES` that is not referenced in the `INTO` and the concatenation of the row data is incorrect;

```
$sql_write = "INSERT INTO `table2`.`load_records` 
       (`id`, `data1`,`data2`,`date`) 
VALUES ('.$row['id'].', '.$row['data1']', '.$row['data2']', '.$row['date']', NULL);";
```

should be:

```
$sql_write = "INSERT INTO `table2`.`load_records` 
       (`id`, `data1`,`data2`,`date`) 
VALUES ('".$row['id']."', '".$row['data1']."', '".$row['data2']."', '".$row['date']."');";
```

Or you need to update the `INTO` to include an extra column that accepts `NULL`

#### See also:

- The PHP reference on [`mysqli_result::fetch_assoc`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: What version oh php and what OS?

Comment: The OP is using mysqli. can't be mixed with the deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: based on the new error posted in these comments I would suggest looking at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8225474/5971390

Comment: No, simply don't use the mysql_* functions. Stay with mysqli  ...or PDO.

Comment: got it working, copying the echo results into phpadmin allowed me to isolate the issue, thanks everyone for help and direction on what should have been a very easy task

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in my comment, first your select statement should be:

```
"SELECT id, data1, data2, date FROM `table1`";
```

Furthermore, the insert statement should be (see the use of concatenation of strings):

```
"INSERT INTO `table2`.`load_records` (`id`, `data1`,`data2`,`date`) VALUES ('".$row['id']."', '".$row['data1']."', '".$row['data2']."', '".$row['date']."', NULL);";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your script, as already pointed out.
But you might also be interested in the [INSERT INTO ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) variant of the INSERT syntax.

```
<?php
$query = '
    INSERT INTO
        table2
        (`id`, `data1`,`data2`,`date`)
    SELECT 
        `id`, `data1`,`data2`,`date`
    FROM
        table1
';
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if ( !$result ) {
    trigger_error('error: ' . $mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
else {
    echo $mysqli->affected_rows, ' rows have been transfered';
}
```