# Xampp/Php: extension mysql is not compiled into Php

Tags: php, xampp, pear, mdb2

"extension mysql is not compiled into Php" is an error i keep receiving. Throughout research I have found that the mysql.dll is no longer used in the version of xampp i have. I am using PEAR and an array `$dsn`. Now I do see that an `pdo_mysql.dll` is loaded in the `ext/` but I am still not sure how to fix this error within xampp.

```
$dsn = array(
            'phptype' => 'mysql',
            'username' => "",
            'hostspec' => "localhost",
            'database' => "witit",
        );
```

So this was marked for duplicate but it is not the same issue because I have removed the semi-colon to add the `extension=mysql.dll` and that did not solve my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin - The MySQL Extension is Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225198/phpmyadmin-the-mysql-extension-is-missing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why this was marked as a duplicate when it was not. The problem was that the `MDB2_Driver_Mysql` doesn't work, and the `extension=php_mysql.dll` doesnt load the extension. So what I found out was I had to download the `MDB2_Driver_mysqli` that worked for the xampp.