# Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress ubuntu 18.10

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

/etc/init.d/mysql status is **running active**

When I am trying to install php, I get this message:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package php5.6-mysql
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php5.6-mysql'
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-mysql'

Comment: check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225198/phpmyadmin-the-mysql-extension-is-missing

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: sorry for the wrong question and thank your for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

To find out what packages exist in the repositories:

```
sudo apt search <package_name>
```

This will give you a list of packages that you can install, and this will allow you to check if the package `php5.6-mysql` actually exists (which it probably doesn't).

Once you've done that, you'll be able to install the correct package that you need!

The packages you probably want are `php5-mysql` and `mysql-server`.

So simply run:

```
sudo apt install php5-mysql mysql-server
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Package php5-mysql is not available, but is referred to by another package.This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source. Is it because of ubuntu 18.10?
I have mysql-server installed.